# Create a shell script to execute multiple commands

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, sh, executable

Here is what i want to do... I want to write a script which sends all the files in a folder as an input to the command2.

I know pipes are used to send the output of one command to another but in my case, when i do

```
ls | command
```

What this does is it sends the output of ls ( i.e. all the files in the folder ) as a single input. Instead, I want that the individual files are sent as an argument to the command2, one by one.

Can anyone please help me out i really searched a lot for it but didn't find much.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886295/how-do-i-list-one-filename-per-output-line-in-linux would that help?

Comment: Chances are that `find` or a loop of files in your directory will do a better job of whatever you are trying to do. It's [generally considered a bad idea to parse the output](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls) of `ls`

Comment: In this particular case, of course, simply `command *` is superior, and avoids [parsing `ls` output](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @Sonamor : I understood the question in that the OP want to invoke *command* many times, once for each input file.

Comment: @ChintanMehta: How about `echo *|xargs -n 1 your_command` ? Note that in this case, *your_command* doesn't get the (single) filename via stdin, but as command line argument.

Answer (score 2):

use any of the below methods, but i recommend the first one, since no subshell is been created

```
for files in *;do
   if [[ -f "$files" ]];then
       echo "$files"
   fi
done


while read line;do
   if [[ -f "$line" ]];then
       echo "$line"
   fi
done < <(ls)
```

Comment: test -f  is useful to avoid a directory

Comment: I want to encrypt those files with gpg command. Now your first script runs well, but when i replace the 3rd line with,
      
      _gpg -e -r "Recipient"_

I get the following output
      
       _usage: gpg [options] --encrypt [filename]_ 

Instead of running that command

Comment: the fault is not from the script, the fault is from your `gpg` command, what is "Recipient" ?

Comment: recipient is the user whose key it is. BTW, i have used the same gpg command without the shellscript and it works flawlessly so i don't think its that @0.sh

Comment: bro pass in the filename to gpg `gpg -e -r "Recipient" "$files"`

Comment: problem solved ?? @ChintanMehta

Comment: Yeah!! used _gpg -e -r "Chintan Mehta" $eachfilename_  
Thanks!!

Comment: @ChintanMehta accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find`, for example:

```
$ cat do.sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

printf "arg: %s\n" "$1"
$ touch {1..10}
$ find . -type f -exec ./do.sh {} \;
arg: ./6
arg: ./10
arg: ./5
arg: ./3
arg: ./9
arg: ./2
arg: ./8
arg: ./do.sh
arg: ./1
arg: ./4
arg: ./7
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you're doing here. And yes, I tried running this file in my folder. It didn't work

Comment: What file? What didn't work?

Comment: Nevermind, I used another method and it worked. Do check out in the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xargs`.

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 -l command
```

this will print all of the files in your current directory, separating the names by null chars, then `xargs` take them, one at a time (`-l`) and invokes `command` using each file as an argument.